# Python Socket Receiving Doubles

Tags: python, sockets, casting, double

I need a python program to use a TCP connection(to another program) to retrieve sets of 9 bytes.

The first of the nine bytes represents a char, and the rest represent a double.

How can I extract this information from a python socket?  Will I have to do the maths manually to convert the stream data or is there a better way?

Comment: by bits you mean bytes right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at python `struct`

http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

So something like

```
from struct import unpack

unpack('cd',socket_read_buffer)

--> ('c', 3.1415)
```

Be careful of Endianness.

Answer (score 0):

If both client and server are written in python, I'd suggest you use pickle. It lets you convert python variables to bytes and then back to python variables with their original type.

```html
#SENDER
import pickle, struct

#convert the variable to bytes with pickle
bytes = pickle.dumps(original_variable)
#convert its size to a 4 bytes int (in bytes)
#I: 4 bytes unsigned int
#!: network (= big-endian)
length = struct.pack("!I", len(bytes))
a_socket.sendall(length)
a_socket.sendall(bytes)
```

```html
#RECEIVER
import pickle, struct

#This function lets you receive a given number of bytes and regroup them
def recvall(socket, count):
    buf = b""
    while count > 0:
        newbuf = socket.recv(count)
        if not newbuf: return None
        buf += newbuf
        count -= len(newbuf)
    return buf


length, = struct.unpack("!I", recvall(socket, 4)) #we know the first reception is 4 bytes
original_variable = pickle.loads(recval(socket, length))
```